# Select the Count and Maximum Value

Tags: sql

I have the following table where the price and Units changes daily

```
item  Price  Units 

Milk  10    5
Milk  20    6
Milk  5     12
```

I want to output the Max price and total units present for each item 
i.e

```
Milk  20.  23
```

My Query :

```
select
  item
from
  sometable
  inner join (
    select max(Price) Max_Price, item
    from sometable
    group by item
  ) as max on max.item = sometable.item and max.Max_Price = sometable.Price
```

How i calculate Total count efficiently as i don't want other joins.

Comment: You have your answer in inner join. Just remove outer query.

Comment: which SQL engine are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will do, you group over items, and for each group you select `max(Price)` for maximum price in a group and `sum(Units)` for sum of units in a group

```
select item, max(Price) Max_Price, sum(Units) Total_Units 
from sometable
group by item
```

Comment: Nice. Simple and elegant. Will work on multiple database engines.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query,

```
select item, max(price), count(units) from table_name 
group by item;
```